# Binding to dynamically created controls

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm having trouble binding values to dynamically created controls. When a user loads a custom file and that file will have a unknown number of arguments. Arguments have a Group property that when grouped will dynamically add tabItems to a tabControl. I then loop through the arguments and add a label and, for now, a textbox to a grid inside the tabs. though i intend to use different controls depending on the arument type. I want to bind the argument Value property to the textbox. The tabs, labels and textboxes are added fine but, no value binding

He if my not yet re-factored solution so far;

```
    myTab.Items.Clear();

    var args = viewModel.Arguments;
    var groups = args.GroupBy(arg => arg.Groups);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    TabItemExt tab = new TabItemExt();
    tab.Header = group.Key;

    Grid grid = new Grid();

    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

    int count = 0;
    foreach (var argument in group)
    {
        RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Insert(count, newRow);

        LabelTextBlock label = new LabelTextBlock();
        label.Text = argument.DisplayName;

        Grid.SetRow(label, count);
        Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = viewModel.Arguments[argument.Name];
        //binding.Source = argument
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");

        textBox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

        Grid.SetRow(textBox, count);
        Grid.SetColumn(textBox, 1);

        grid.Children.Add(label);
        grid.Children.Add(textBox);
        count += 1; 
    }

    tab.Content = grid;
    myTab.Items.Add(tab);    
}
```

Comment: Am I to assume that `viewModel.Arguments[argument.Name].Value` is a valid property? And why not use something like an `ItemsControl` to generate your controls from XAML instead of code-behind?

Comment: viewModel.Arguments[argument.Name].Value is a valid property yes.

Comment: Is it publicly available for the View to find when it tries to bind to it's data?

Comment: yes it is, i think i know where you're going with this. But this is a simplified version of what i'm doing there are also sub groups. Hence why i thought doing this in the behind code of the view would make sense. But willing to try anything.

Comment: I would suggest downloading [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and running it while your application is running. You can use it to see what exactly your TextBox is binding to

Comment: So, using snoop to have a look and the textboxes, the property TextBlock.Text has the correct value. The SelectedText property is empty. Still no text.

Comment: Devil was in the detail textBox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding); should of been textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding); Damn you un-intellisense. Thanks you the snoop recommendation Rachel.

Comment: lol I re-read your comment 3 times before I noticed the difference. I'm always doing that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textBox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

should have been

```
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

just a little over dependent on intellisense.